# How to avoid DB exceptions when changing users role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, user-roles

I have such situation: I have Users table and I divide users by type: Admins, Managers, Customer.

Managers can be created only with Organizer model( organizer has_many managers) and it is creating on nested form.

I want to **upgrade Customer to Manager** if someone is trying to create Manager with already registered Customer's email.

**Current situation:**

When I'm trying to create Manager with Customer's email it showing me database error. I can make some validation to change Customer type -> to -> Manager, but it still wants to save Manager record and obviously failing and giving me next error.

```
   ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
```

How I can handle this **RIGHT** ?

P.S. Here is my models code:

```
 class Organizer
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :managers
 has_many :managers
 ___________________

 class Manager < User
 belongs_to :organizer

 ___________________

 class Customer < User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check if such a record with specified email ID exists in your Users table.

- If yes, update the role col in that record to Manager,
- else insert a new record.

Comment: it easy to say) I need to validate manager's email very time it is changing or creating, so how I could skip saving if this email is already taken ?

Comment: select count(rowid) from Users where where email='<your email here>;' If it returns greater than 0, you already have the user.

Comment: I can find customer with this ecode: `Customer.find_by_email(self.email)` but how I can skip saving record ? And how I can do skipping record saving ? It seems, that you don't undersand problem. I will write more in question.

Comment: using if/else conditionals...
if(customer exists)
update role
else
insert customer

Comment: Where I should put if statements ? In validation or some callback ?